# Bound for graph's size with cycles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and such that every cycle in $G$
>   has length $\leq3$. Then $e(G)\leq\dfrac{3(n-1)}{2}$.
>   (where $e(G)$ is the number of edges of the graph $G$)

I think it could be a good idea to prove this by induction, but do not know how to use the bound for the length of the cycles.

Comment: I don't understand, if graph is simple how can it have 2 cycle? Or I don't understand the term simple.

Comment: Simple means that the graph is undirected, unweighted and is not a multigraph (graphs with more than one edge between vertices)

Comment: So the only cycles wich are possible are 3-cycles?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Because 2-cycles will mean that 2 vertex are joined by 2 edges, and we do not allow them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose graph has 3-cycles $C_1,C_2,...C_k$ and $\varepsilon$ edges. Each cycle has 3 edges and because of condition that each cycle is of length 3 every edge is in at most one 3-cycle. So we have $$   k\leq {\varepsilon\over 3}$$

Suppose graph has spanning sub tree $T$ which has exactly $n-1$ edges. Then each edge which is not in $T$ (we have $\varepsilon -n+1$ of those) must be on exactly one 3-cycle. But we can't have more those edges than the 3-cycles. So we have
$$ \varepsilon -n+1\leq k \leq {\varepsilon\over 3} \Longrightarrow \varepsilon \leq {3n-3\over 2} $$

Comment: For greater generality, we can let $T$ be a full spanning forest (the union of spanning trees on each connected component). This still has at most $n-1$ edges (fewer if the graph is not connected) and is still a maximal acyclic subgraph.

Comment: Yes, yes, I assumed graph is connected. But if not you can proceed as you said.

Comment: @JohnWatson, when you say "Then each edge which is not in T (we have $\epsilon - n +1$ of those) must be on exactly one 3-cycle", I do not see why this is true.

Comment: Say we have an edge $AB$ which is on two 3-cycles, say $ABC$ and $ABD$. But then we have a 4-cycle $ADBC$. It is exactly the same argument as I had when I count the number of all possible 3-cycles.

Comment: Yes, I understand that if one is in two 3-cycles, you have a 4-cycle; but why having those edges in $T$ makes them unable to be on a 3-cycle. You can have a spanning tree with edges that belong to a cycle, can't you? I do not see the implication "edge in tree" $\rightarrow$ "edge not in cycle".

Comment: But I was looking relation with edges not on the tree and the cycles. I'm not interesting what is happening with the edges in the tree.

Comment: Why can't we have more edges that aren't in $T$ than 3-cycles?

Comment: EDIT: I saw that. It is because every edge that is not in the tree is exactly in (only) one cycle, so there cannot be more edges than cycles.

Comment: Could it be that the graph do not have a spanning sub tree with $n-1$ edges? Or you can always find one?

Comment: If it is connected you can do this always.